# Magento tutorial create a module for the backend (admin page)

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Does anyone know a good tutorial for this subject. I want to create a module (extension) with more than one page. The extension must contain one overview page and a form to create a item.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm clearly biased, but the [Magento for PHP MVC Developers](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) series I'm working on does a pretty good job of introducing core Magento development topics.